# ¿puedo traer todos los registros de una tabla y contarlos al mismo tiempo con laravel 8?

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-8

Estoy haciendo una especie de dashboard en laravel 8. Tengo una tabla "products" con su respectivo modelo y controlador, quiero traer todos los registros de esa tabla y saber cuantos registros hay, sé que para traer todos los registros usaría `Products::all();` y para contarlos usaría `Products::count();` luego los asignaría a una variable respectivamente y lo pasaria a la vista con `compact` pero ¿puedo hacer estas 2 cosas en una sola consulta? o simplemente no se puede.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu primera consulta de acuerdo con la pregunta será la única que necesites, ya que al enviarla a la vista solo requerirás acceder al método `count()` en dicha colección para  visualizar el total.

Entonces en tu controlador:

```
$tuVariable = Modelo::all();
```

En tu vista podrás:

1.- Iterar toda la colección

2.- Obtener el conteo con:

```
  $tuVariable->count();
```

Comment: gracias amigo, me funcionó, esta es la respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer esto.

Crea una función que retorne un array y después asigna el retorno de la función a dos variables

```
function unaConsulta(){
    return [
        \App\Models\Products::all(), 
        Products::count(),
    ];
}
```

Obtener los valores:

```
Route::get('/test', function () {
    [$products, $countProducts] = unaConsulta();

    return $products;// obtienes todos los registros de la BBDD

    //return $countProducts; obtienes cuantos registros hay
});
```

Espero te sirva

Comment: Él decía en una sola consulta xd

Comment: @alentin a verdad xd

Comment: Además hacer un count a una colección extensa de productos en la aplicación no es óptimo, en todo caso le dejaría el count al gestor de base de datos

Comment: ¿Puedes explicarme porque no es optimo? por favor y gracias

Comment: @BetaM lo hice así para dar a entender que valor tiene cada variable, pero comentando un return se puede entender mejor, editado.

Comment: @Ivandez gracias por la respuesta, aunque es mas complejo de la forma en que lo planteas.